# How to get the sum value of two rows for this mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with mysql Query. i need to calculate the sum of two rows amount value. here my query is

```
   SELECT cs.school_id, 
          SUM( ss.strength * cr.rate_offered ) AS str
     FROM tbl_school_course_strength cs, 
          tbl_school_strength ss, 
          tbl_course_rates cr
    WHERE cs.school_id = ss.school_id
      AND ss.class >= cs.from_class
      AND ss.class <= cs.to_class
      AND cs.school_id = cr.school_id
      AND cs.course_id = cr.course_id
      AND cs.school_id = '$school_name[school_id]'
 GROUP BY cs.school_id
```

here the Output come like this

```
school_id   str 

----------------      
28  326250
29  218250
30  372900
```

Now i want the Sum of these three School_id amount values. Could you help me how to get the sum. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your tried php code

Comment: remover cs,school_id from the select and dont group by it

Comment: same as above sql code i used. I tried in mysql command prompt.the output will come like above. I need Sum of displayed output amount

Answer (score 1):

update your mysql query to the query below which does not contain group by and schoold id.

```
SELECT SUM( ss.strength * cr.rate_offered ) AS str
FROM tbl_school_course_strength cs, tbl_school_strength ss, tbl_course_rates cr
WHERE cs.school_id = ss.school_id
AND ss.class >= cs.from_class
AND ss.class <= cs.to_class
AND cs.school_id = cr.school_id
AND cs.course_id = cr.course_id
AND cs.school_id = '$school_name[school_id]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(str) strtotal FROM
(SELECT cs.school_id, SUM( ss.strength * cr.rate_offered ) AS str
FROM tbl_school_course_strength cs, tbl_school_strength ss, tbl_course_rates cr
WHERE cs.school_id = ss.school_id
AND ss.class >= cs.from_class
AND ss.class <= cs.to_class
AND cs.school_id = cr.school_id
AND cs.course_id = cr.course_id
AND cs.school_id = '$school_name[school_id]'
GROUP BY cs.school_id)x
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select sum(str) as total from (SELECT cs.school_id, SUM( ss.strength * cr.rate_offered )     AS str
FROM tbl_school_course_strength cs, tbl_school_strength ss, tbl_course_rates cr
WHERE cs.school_id = ss.school_id
AND ss.class >= cs.from_class
AND ss.class <= cs.to_class
AND cs.school_id = cr.school_id
AND cs.course_id = cr.course_id
AND cs.school_id = '$school_name[school_id]'
GROUP BY cs.school_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select SUM(str) as total from (SELECT cs.school_id, SUM( ss.strength * cr.rate_offered ) AS str
FROM tbl_school_course_strength cs, tbl_school_strength ss, tbl_course_rates cr
WHERE cs.school_id = ss.school_id
AND ss.class >= cs.from_class
AND ss.class <= cs.to_class
AND cs.school_id = cr.school_id
AND cs.course_id = cr.course_id
AND cs.school_id = '$school_name[school_id]'
GROUP BY cs.school_id) as temp
```

Comment: Yeah its Coming in Sql command Prompt. while i given this query in Php total value is not came. what is the problem? @yashasvee

Comment: Here i added code. Please check this link . https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9000588

Comment: sorry couldn't find a solution.